# Space allocation for Solaris on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, solaris

I am about to install Solaris on top of my Windows through Virtualbox. I have decided to allocate a storage of 50 GB to it. Now will the 50 GB be taken from the empty space available in that drive (F://), or it may encroach upon existing data, clear it and occupy it? If not, if the limit exceeds 50 GB at some point, and there is no space left in the drive, will VB take empty space from other drives or overwrite existing data in F drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on if it is dynamicaly allocated for fixed size.  the vhd is just a file that sits on some filesystem.  afaik you can not span to multiple hdd's  vmware might but never tried to find out.  vmware is able to split the image in to several 2gb files.

to the os that disk is what vbox tells it is.  if you used "VBoxManage modifyhd OldDisk.vdi –-resize 30000" command you could make the used vdi change size.  it would be like ghosting a partition to a larger disk you would have unalloceted space after the original partitions. when the os fills its 50gb quota it will error like any normal phisical disk saying out of space.  you have to use normal fs tools to either expand the partitions after giving the vdi more room or delete stuff.

Comment: It is dynamically allocated. So while it grows up, will it consume space from the free space available, or may it encroach on used space too?

Comment: it is a file just like any other on the host system. when you are out of space on that host drive that's it. its no different then say recording a mp4 from your video camera that file keeps expanding till your os tells the app no more room.